# Splitting array to alternate 4 elements in c

Tags: arrays, c, split

Lets say
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

then i want
x=[1,2,3,4,9,10,11,12]
y=[5,6,7,8,13,14,15,16]

I could do this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int array[16] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
int *firstHalf = malloc(8 * sizeof(int));
int *secondHalf = malloc(8 * sizeof(int));

memcpy(firstHalf, array, 4 * sizeof(int));
memcpy(secondHalf, array + 4,4 * sizeof(int));
memcpy(firstHalf+4, array+8, 4 * sizeof(int));
memcpy(secondHalf+4, array + 12,4 * sizeof(int));
for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    printf("First %d\n",firstHalf[i]);
}  for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    printf("Second %d\n",secondHalf[i]);
}
}
```

I did this but need a solution to put it into for loop to make it expandable

Please suggest me on how can it be done

Comment: I don't see why you begin by copying 8 elements when you only want 4. Copy 4 elements to the first array, copy the next 4 elements to the other array, and repeat, watching out for the end condition, and incomplete sets at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer but if you have better suggestion let me know

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int array[32] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32};
int *firstHalf = malloc(16 * sizeof(int));
int *secondHalf = malloc(16 * sizeof(int));
//for (int h=0;h<9;h+=4)
for (int l=0,h=0;l<33,h<16;l=l+8,h=h+4)
{
    memcpy(firstHalf+h, array+l, 4 * sizeof(int));
memcpy(secondHalf+h, array + 4+l,4 * sizeof(int));
}
for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
{
    printf("First %d\n",firstHalf[i]);
}  for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
{
    printf("Second %d\n",secondHalf[i]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what parameter it is, that you want to be expandable, so I recreated your code with two parameters N=2 is the number of vectors you want in the end, M=4 is the size of the chunks you want copied together:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 2 // split in N=2 arrays
#define M 4 // always copy M=4 items together

int main()
{
int array[16] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
int *parts[N];
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    parts[i] = malloc(16 * sizeof(int) / N);
}
for (int i=0;i<16/N/M;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        memcpy(parts[j]+i*M, array + i*M*N + j*M, M * sizeof(int));
    }
}
for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    printf("First %d\n",parts[0][i]);
}  for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    printf("Second %d\n",parts[1][i]);
}
}
```

You should definitely change M, N to meaningful names and insert names for M*N etc. accordingly to the context and pay extra attention if your numbers aren't divisible as in this example.